# Logstash gelf not receiving messages

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, monolog

I'm trying to send my symfony2 logs to a logstash server but the server doesn't receive the logs =/

My logstash conf in `/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf` is

```
input {
    gelf {
        port => "12201"
        host => "0.0.0.0"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
    stdout {
        debug => true
        debug_format => "json"
    }
}
```

The files in /var/log/logstash are empty. With monolog, I caught the sended strings :

```
{"_facility":"request",
"_ctxt_route_parameters":"...",
"_ctxt_request_uri":"...",
"version":"1.0",
"short_message":"...",
"full_message":null,
"host":"dev",
"timestamp":1462196712,
"level":6}
```

What is wrong with my config ? I tested to get elasticsearch indexes :

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
health status index   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   .kibana   1   1          1            0      3.1kb          3.1kb
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Do you see the data in the stdout output? What version of Logstash are you running?

Comment: @Val I don't see anything in the std output. Logstash version is `2.3.2`

Comment: Then it probably means gelf is not receiving any events. How do you know that logs are getting generated?

Comment: I got the same problem, can't get it to work. Packets are sent, but I don't see it in elasticsearch. Well, I don't see it in `iptraf` utility either..